# Qt 5.2 mingw package, Issue with QtCreator loading plugins

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I’ve downloaded QT 5.2 mingw. Then i had trouble with QtCreator loading the plugings(compiled with mingw). After that i found that the QtCreator is built with MSVC 2010!!!! 
So why in Qt 5.2 (which is built with Mingw), its QtCreator is built with MSVC?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because all Qt Creator releases are built once and repackaged in the various installers. It's not a good reason, and might even be a bad reason given your problem, but it's probably the reason. Note the Qt SDK is not meant to be used for actual Qt (Creator) development (you will use the git repositories for that), which is probably why nobody ever ran into this mismatch.

Note you can easily rebuild Qt Creator from source. It's as simple as

```
qmake ../qt-creator-3.0.0 -r
mingw32-make release
```

If you have a `qt-creator-3.0.0-build` directory next to the extracted source.